# android-can not play video by using VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

it's very strange , the VideoView does not play flv and mp4 videos . It doesn't play 3gp videos with the video size of 704*576 also .

it only play 3gp videos with screen size of 352*288 and lower , so I get a very very bad video resolution and it bothers alot .

Why is that ?How can I play flv and mp4 videos with good quality ? What should be the videos setting to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to pay FLV videos you need to build your own player,because few android mobile doesn't support  FLV

Comment: @Giridharan thanks for reply , How can I do so ?

Comment: check this link it will help you to build your own player:  https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle

Comment: you can also add vlc player to your application: https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample